# Rails Issue with User Cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce, cart

I've got a Rails cart for a customer which works but only on the second attempt of trying to 'add-to-cart'.

So every time I click 'add to cart', the cart is empty the first time. But on second attempt, the item is added to cart.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the customer controller code:

```
 class Customer::CartsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   def show
     @cart = if current_user
     current_user.cart ||= Cart.find_by(session[:cart_id])
     session[:cart_id] = nil if current_user.cart.purchased_at
  end
  if session[:cart_id].nil?
    current_user.cart = Cart.create!(user_id: params[:id])
    session[:cart_id] = current_user.cart.id 
  end
  @cart = current_user.cart
  end
end
```

Regular Carts controller

```
 class CartsController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

 def index
  @carts = Cart.all
 end

def show
end

def new
 @cart = Cart.new
end

def edit
end

def create
@cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @cart.save
    format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.'}
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
     if @cart.update(cart_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
     else
       format.html { render :edit }
       format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
   end

 def destroy
  @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
  session[:cart_id] = nil
 end
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Your Cart is currently empty.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
 def set_cart
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def cart_params
  params[:cart]
end

def invalid_cart
  logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Invalid cart'
end
end
```

Line Items controller create method

```
def create
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id, params[:size])

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to customer_cart_path }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously working on cart i had the same issue as far as i remember it came from current_cart method sitting in your application controller

I ended up changing it to this

```
def current_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id]) 
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id 
    @cart
end
```

also prior to @cart.add_.... I have the call for the method in my lineitems controller create method

```
@cart = current_cart
```

**Edit 1**

this is my lineitems create method I think you are missing a creation of cart if there is none

```
@lineitem = Lineitem.new(lineitem_params)
@cart = current_cart
item = Item.find(lineitem_params[:item_id])
@lineitem = @cart.addItem(item.id,@lineitem.quantity)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't have the `current_cart` method in application controller. I created a Customer controller that inherits from the Carts controller (posted above) - instead of using the `current cart` method. Tried calling `@cart = current_user.cart` method in the LineItems controller before `cart.add_product` but it didn't work either.

Comment: I did it in a slightly different way, i create a cart everytime a user is created. So in my user model, i have this callback > `after_create :default_cart`

 `def default_cart
      self.create_cart
    end`

Comment: It works, but for some reason. Line Items don't go into the cart the first time, you have to sorta go back to the store again and add to cart a second time before it gets added.

Comment: But you create the cart when user is created what happens when user logs in next time?

Comment: Would the 'default cart' created at sign up, still exist when the user logs in again? I don't know...any idea how i could check?

Comment: not to my knowledge as when you sign out you technically run session destroy meaning your session[:cart_id]  gets wiped with it. also with the idea of cart being created on user create how would you handle user creating a new cart after checkout (shopping with you again)?

Comment: There is a `purchased_at` column that gets updated if checkout is successful, which creates a new cart after. The `show` method in `Customer::CartsController` has that code. So it seems, i need to create a cart when the User logs in right? How do i go about that?

Comment: I used the current_cart method that sat in my application controller and it would get called any time the user would try to add an item to the cart the method is in my original answer also as the call to it shown in edit that shows my line items create method

Comment: Oh i see. But can i use that as well as the show method in my `Customer::CartsController`? Or its one or the other?

Comment: i would say you can use both reason i used it in application controler is to have it accessible globally i have a tutorial pdf its an initial version that i had to apply minor changes to if you want to have a look. also if my assistance was useful please up vote the answer

Comment: Just tried it, still doesn't work....yeah, Could i please have a look at the pdf?

Comment: http://res.cloudinary.com/dp20nga5l/image/upload/v1465898393/Shopping_2016_yxvhid.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what is going on here without seeing the full code. For instance, the question is primarily about a bug that occurs when trying to add a product to the cart, but the definition of the `add_product` method is not shown.

I can offer a couple pieces of advice that should help. First, the `show` method of the `Customer::CartsController` was hard to follow. I've refactored it to remove the unnecessary nested if statement, and reduce the number of conditionals.

```
class Customer::CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    return unless current_user

    current_user.cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])

    # if the cart has already been purchased, reset to a new cart
    if current_user.cart.purchased_at
      current_user.cart = Cart.create!(user_id: params[:id])
      session[:cart_id] = current_user.cart.id 
    end

    @cart = current_user.cart
  end
end
```

Second, when dealing with a bug like this, you should find yourself with a much more specific question (if not the answer to your problem). In order to arrive at such a specific question, you need to debug to find out exactly what the problem is. You can do this in a couple of ways:

1. The simplest option is to put some "probe" statements in your code. For example, if you need to confirm whether or not the `purchased_at` value is set in the Customer::CartsController show action when you click to add to the cart, you can put in a statement like `puts "purchased_at is set"`
   within the body of the if statement. The output will show up in the Rails server output, which you can watch in another window while interacting with your site in the web browser.
2. The preferred option is to use a debugger. I recommend `pry`, which you can find and read about here: https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger.

What you should be trying to do with either of these techniques is to find out where what happens during runtime does not match your expectations of what your code should have done, or what would facilitate the behavior you expect as a user. Ultimately, this will often result in isolating a specific area of code where things don't make sense, making the question much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is wrong in `Customer::CartsController` show action

```
  @cart = if current_user
    current_user.cart ||= Cart.find_by(session[:cart_id])
    session[:cart_id] = nil if current_user.cart.purchased_at
  end
```

That will always make `@cart == nil`

I think it should be something like

```
  @cart = if current_user
    current_user.cart ||= Cart.find_by(session[:cart_id])
    session[:cart_id] = nil if current_user.cart.purchased_at
    current_user.cart
  end
```

That is, the last part of the `if` statement needs to return the object that will be assigned to `@cart`

Comment: That doesn't work either. Throws up an `undefined method `add_product' for nil:NilClass` error.

The error happens in the create method of the LineItems controller - Edited question with the LineItems Controller create action - So basically, cart is passing an empty variable